# Double quotes in DB breaking HTML Output

Tags: php, pdo

I've tried everything, and I still can't figure it out. `addslahes()`, `str_replace()`, `htmlentities()`, I just can't understand why double quotes are not displaying on my website.

```
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_settings` WHERE `user_session` = '$user_session'");
$sql -> execute();

$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $advertising_1 = $row['advertising_1'];
    $advertising_2 = $row['advertising_2'];
    $website_name = $row['website_name'];
    $website_url = $row['website_url'];
    $statistics = $row['statistics'];
}
echo '<input type="text" name="website_name" placeholder="Your Website URL" value="'. $website_name. '" />' ?>
```

Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong here? Problem arises  with Double quotes in my string. Single quotes was fixed with mysql_escape but it appears to be deprecated.

Comment: can you give one example for the your value, which you want to insert

Comment: @arif_suhail_123  Consider `$website_name` = `"example.com"` (notice the double quotes in the website name.

Comment: if you use binding problem will be solved, `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);` This the code i got from php manual website, from the chris link, and this is hint for your code and should work `<?php 
$str = addslashes('"example.com"');
echo($str); 
// and than insert this $str variable
?>` if your query is fine

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 dont use `addslashes` for DB escaping. From the manual page itself, `Please note that use of addslashes() for database parameter escaping can be cause of security issues on most databases.`

Comment: @chirs85 i did not know that, thanks for teaching me some thing valuable,

Comment: Nothing seem to work guys. @chris85, I tried the bindParam and still not working. I somehow realized that if my column in my table is varchar it doesn't work but with text, it works.

Comment: @chris85 No errors, it updates fine, except when there is  double quotes it just doesn't show it. It's just stripping it away or strips away anything between the double quotes. Otherwise no actual errors, check edited code.

Comment: @nTuply it may sound silly, are you sure you got the double qoutes around your value, can you just check like echo variable or some thing, so you can be sure you got the double qoute around it

Comment: I just checked my DB and the double quotes are actually inserted in it. The problem is actually with my select statement. This is actually weird, since it just doesn't show what's in between the double quotes and strips it off when I use the SELECT. So I was dumb it's not the update that's wrong but the select.

Comment: `$website_name` is a variable that stores the name of a website, it can have single or double quotes and it is grabbed from a form and stored in my table. Then I use the select to get it. So for example if I have `"Wow website name"` in my DB (with the double quotes), it doesn't show up. But `$advertising_1` for example just shows up. Only different is that the latter is a `text` and former a `varchar`. I don't get it

Comment: @chris85 Indeed `print_r($result)` shows it properly. I saw the mistake. It was indeed the HTML that was the problem. I was echoing the HTML in double quotes and it wouldn't work. But with single quotes, it now stopped working. So it's all about the quotes. How can that be fixed? Here's my HTML: `<?php echo "<input type='text' name='website_name' placeholder='Your Website URL' value='".$_SESSION['website_name']."' />" ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the data you are outputting to the browser use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and use the quotes constant (ENT_QUOTES) so all quotes are converted to entities. Note this also is how XSS injections are prevented/performed. Elements/attributes are closed when they aren't suppose to be and then malicious code is written.

```
echo htmlspecialchars('Encode all of these "test" test \'test \'', ENT_QUOTES);
```

Output:

```
Encode all of these &quot;test&quot; test &#039;test &#039;
```

and in a browser:

> Encode all of these "test" test 'test '

Also from the code you displayed you are misusing prepared statements. Values need to be bound, not concatenated to your query. This way the PDO driver will handle the quoting/escaping. This could result in similar issues for you in the future, if you continue to use it as you have it. Also opens you to SQL injections.

For more information on prepared statements see: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Excellent. Worked perfectly. I will now read about how to write proper PDO prepared statements and not make the same mistakes in the future. Quick question though, any good informative resources to learn more about security issues and how to prevent them?

Comment: That is a wide topic, but this site has some good documentation, it isn't specific to PHP, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the prepare without variables on the statement and later you add them on the execute() as an array, like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `user_settings` WHERE `user_session` = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$user_session]);
```